# How is the spread syntax used here to turn a number to a string array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, numbers, spread-syntax

I was trying to solve a challenge on one of the coding websites and I saw this in the best solution for that challenge.

Can someone elaborate why this piece of code: `[...a%10+''+a]`

returns the following array: `["2", "1", "1", "2", "2"]`

What is actually happening behind the scenes?

P.S. I am aware that this might not be the best practice, but I am still learning and this seems really interesting.

Comment: What is the value of `a`? Where did it come from?

Comment: @CRice `a` must be either `1122` or `'1122'`.

Comment: `a` is a number. As @Paulpro said, it's 1122.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the original value of `a` is `1122`.

1. `a%10` returns the last digit of `a`, namely `2`.
2. `+''` converts that from a number to a string, `"2"`.
3. `+a` concatenates the full value of `a`, resulting in `"21122"`.
4. Putting this in `[...]` spreads the string into an array of its characters.

Here are all the steps as code:

```js
const a = 1122;
const lastDigit = a % 10;
const lastDigitStr = lastDigit + '';
const newStr = lastDigitStr + a;
const result = [...newStr];
console.dir(result);
```

Comment: Ah, it comes down to the order of execution. Thank you guys for making me realize that.